# MongoDb how to query fields and also query populated fields

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need to query multiple fields from Schema and also one field from populated data.

This is my Restaurant Orders Schema

```
const restaurantOrdersSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
userId: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
    required: [true, 'User id missing from order']
},
address: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Address missing from order'],
},
phoneNumber: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Phone Number missing from order'],
}});
```

This is my query

```
 const restaurantOrders = await RestaurantOrders.find({
        $or : [
            { address : { $regex : searchQuery, $options:"i" } },
            { phoneNumber : { $regex : searchQuery, $options:"i" } }
        ]
    }).populate({
        path : 'userId',
        select : 'email',
        match : {
            email : {
                $regex: searchQuery, 
                $options: 'i' 
            }
        }
    });
```

When I search by address or phoneNumber it returns everything correctly but when I search by email that is being populated from field userId I receive empty array

Comment: That seems to be as describe in the docs at https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html: `The match option doesn't filter out Story documents. If there are no documents that satisfy match, you'll get a Story document with an empty fans array.`  You will probably need to use Array.filter, or similar, to eliminate those with an empty userId array.